# É possível acessar a chave através do valor:

Tags: python, algoritmo, dicionário

Em dicionários, em Python, é possível acessar uma chave através do valor? Há algum método que inverta chave/valor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `dict` não possui nenhum método nativo para isso. Mas existe uma manobra que pode ser feita.

Você pode utilizar o método `values`, que retornará uma `list`. Daí você pega o índice dessa lista e obtém os valores da outra lista gerada pelo método `keys`.

Confuso? Então vamos a um exemplo:

```
valores = {"valor_16" : 16, "valor_17" : 17}

valores.keys()[valores.values().index(16)]; // "valor_16"
```

Resposta original no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: Muito obrigado!